# Problem in Inserting data into Database using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am facing a problem in inserting data into access using jdbc

Problem comes in this statement

plz help

My Table has 6 columns 
columns are id(number) , Namee(Short Text) , age(number) , bsalary(decimal) , rate(decimal) and hrs (number)

```
DBConnect dbconnect = new DBConnect();
dbconnect.getConnection("record.accdb");
Statement statement = dbconnect.getStatement();     

String query = "INSERT INTO sguard " +
                "VALUES (2, '2', 2, 2.5, 2.6, 2);";

        try {
            statement.executeUpdate(query);

        }
```

This is error

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10386 table: SGUARD
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessStatement.java:230)
    at DB.DBManager.writeAuthor(DBManager.java:97)
    at UI.Client.main(Client.java:344)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10386 table: SGUARD
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.executeWrapped(ExecuteUpdate.java:65)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:264)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.execute(ExecuteUpdate.java:48)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessStatement.java:228)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10386 table: SGUARD
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.getException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVLMemory.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVL.indexRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.TransactionManager2PL.addInsertAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.addInsertAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

This is DBCOnnect class for connection and disconnect

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBConnect {

    private static Connection connection = null;
    private static Statement statement = null;

    public static void getConnection(String path) {

        try {

            String p = "D:\\ACP Practice Projects\\Assignment 3.1.1\\record.accdb";
            String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+p;

            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            //connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + path);
            statement  = connection.createStatement();

        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
    public static Statement getStatement() {
        return statement;
    }
    public static void disconnect() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and this is DBManager class

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import UI.Employ;
import UI.Lecturer;
import UI.SecurityGuard;

public class DBManager {

    public static  ArrayList<Employ> viewAuthor(){

        ArrayList<Employ> myList = new ArrayList<Employ>();

        DBConnect dbconnect = new DBConnect();
        dbconnect.getConnection("record.accdb");
        Statement statement = dbconnect.getStatement();     

        String query1 = "SELECT * from lecturer";
        String query2 = "SELECT * from sguard";

        int col1,col3,col6;
        String col2;
        float col4,col5;
        boolean col7;

        try {
            ResultSet resultset1=statement.executeQuery(query1);

            while(resultset1.next()) {
                col1 = resultset1.getInt("id");
                col2 = resultset1.getString("Namee");
                col3 = resultset1.getInt("age");
                col4 = resultset1.getFloat("bsalary");
                col5 = resultset1.getFloat("rate");
                col6 = resultset1.getInt("courses");

                myList.add(new Lecturer(col1,col2,col3,col4,col6,col5));
                /*System.out.println(col1);System.out.println(col2);System.out.println(col3);System.out.println(col4);System.out.println(col5);System.out.println(col6);System.out.println(col7);*/

            }

            ResultSet resultset2=statement.executeQuery(query2);

            while(resultset2.next()) {
                col1 = resultset2.getInt("id");
                col2 = resultset2.getString("Namee");
                col3 = resultset2.getInt("age");
                col4 = resultset2.getFloat("bsalary");
                col5 = resultset2.getFloat("rate");
                col6 = resultset2.getInt("hrs");

                myList.add(new SecurityGuard(col1,col2,col3,col4,col6,col5));   
                /*System.out.println(col1);System.out.println(col2);System.out.println(col3);System.out.println(col4);System.out.println(col5);System.out.println(col6);System.out.println(col7);*/

            }

            //System.out.println(col1 +"  ." + col2);

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            DBConnect.disconnect();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < myList.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(myList.get(j).toString());
        }


        return myList;




    }

    public static boolean writeAuthor(ArrayList<Employ> mylist){



        DBConnect dbconnect = new DBConnect();
        dbconnect.getConnection("record.accdb");
        Statement statement = dbconnect.getStatement();     

        String query = "INSERT INTO sguard " +
                "VALUES (2, '2', 2, 2.5, 2.6, 2);";

        try {
            //ResultSet resultset=statement.executeQuery(query);
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
            //statement.execute(query, 6);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            DBConnect.disconnect();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < mylist.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(mylist.get(j).toString());
        }


        return false;
    }



}
```

Comment: id should not be inserted, it should be generated, this is your problem

Comment: Without seeing the *full* table structure (i.e. including constraints) or the existing data we can't say for certain what the issue is. The most likely problem given that error message is that one of the columns has a unique constraint on it (probably your ID column) and you're trying to insert a duplicate value into it.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: First explicitly list the target columns in the `INSERT` statement to make sure everything goes where it should go.

Comment: Hint: The "PK" in `SYS_PK_10386` stands for "Primary Key". You are trying to insert a row with a primary key value that already exists in the table.

Comment: Very Very Thanks Gord Thompson , I removed ID as Primary Key and I worked .....However ,  I was not inserting duplicate data into ID which violate Primary Key Criteria.